# Encoding subdirectories with spaces using Chef remote_directory

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I've got a cookbook that works fine using Test Kitchen and vagrant but on AWS OpsWorks it's getting an error while its using remote_directory to copy a directory structure from the files in my cookbook because it's loading up a server and accessing the files through an URL. I'm new to Chef so not sure of the proper way I'm supposed to be handling this situation. In this case I can rename everything without spaces, but that won't be possible in other situations.

```
URI::InvalidURIError
--------------------
cookbook_file[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/aws configuration info/config.xml] (dynamically defined) had an error: URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://127.0.0.1:8889/file_store/repo/cookbooks/bb-jenkins-master/files/default/jenkins/jobs/aws configuration info/config.xml

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/jenkins-master/recipes/default.rb

28: remote_directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs' do
29:   source      'jenkins/jobs'
30:   owner       'jenkins'
31:   group       'jenkins'
32:   mode        '0755'
33:   files_owner 'jenkins'
34:   files_group 'jenkins'
35:   files_mode  '0644'
36: end
```

[CHEF-5340](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5340?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) was closed because "You'll have to encode things like that yourself with URI escape sequences e.g. %20 for spaces." But I am not seeing a clear way to do that besides using ruby to iterate through the directories myself and not use remote_directory.

Comment: I would assume it means in your cookbook (under `files/default/jenkins/jobs/`) name the child directory `aws%20configuration%20info`. But I'm unsure of what will be the resulting directory.

Comment: Oops I just found out [OpsWorks uses chef_zero for Chef 11.10 stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11.html) so I should be using that in my Test Kitchen.

Comment: @Tensibai, yeah that would cause strange directory names and I'm hoping this is just a recipe configuration issue and not resources structure.